# How to change a button background to image then back to default button when pressed

Tags: java, android, button, background, onclick

Hi i'm new to the site but been lurking for a while. New to programming.

My problem is that i want to press a button,then that button displays an image for a certain amount of time, then returns to its original state. So far I can make the button change/transition to an image but then it doesnt revert back to its button. Or i can make it transition back and forth but without the image.

Ignore other buttons, just trying it for Button1 at the moment. Thanks in advance.

Heres my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button Button1, Button2, Button3, Button4,
                   Button5, Button6, Button7, Button8,
                   Button9, Button10, Button11, Button12;

    private Button ButtonNewGame;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Declaring Buttons/Squares
        Button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
        Button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button2);
        Button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button3);
        Button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button4);
        Button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button5);
        Button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button6);
        Button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button7);
        Button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button8);
        Button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button9);
        Button10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button10);
        Button11= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button11);
        Button12 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button12);
        //Declaring NewGame Button
        ButtonNewGame = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonNewGame);

        //Adding OnClickListeners
        Button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button3.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button4.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button5.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button6.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button7.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button8.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button9.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button10.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button11.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button12.setOnClickListener(this);

        ButtonNewGame.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
        animation.setDuration(1000);
        animation.setInterpolator( new LinearInterpolator());
        animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.ABSOLUTE);
        animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);

        if(v == Button1){
            Button1.startAnimation(animation);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With the Button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); commented out it does the transition and reverts back to original state. Without commenting it shows the image but doesnt revert back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be overkill but you could use an inner [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) that starts when you click the `Button`. This is also when you change the `Button` image. Then, in the `CountDownTimers` [onFinish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html#onFinish%28%29) you set the background of the `Button` to whatever the default is

Comment: Perfect, Thank you very much. Very quick response too. :)

Comment: You are most welcome! Please accept if this solved your question so it may help others easier

Answer (score 0):

Try a `StateListDrawable`

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/a" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/b" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_hovered="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/c" /> <!-- hovered -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/d" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Comment: I don't think that would work as i only want the image displayed for a few seconds once the button has been pressed. After the few seconds I want the button back to its default.

Answer (score 0):

This works i have used it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/ok_button_hover" /> 
  <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/ok_button_hover" /> 
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/ok_button" /> 
</selector>
```